# How to push data to array, When loop object

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to loop object result from API, And push it in to array.

```
historys: any = [];
```

Loop.

```
Object.keys(response['orderdetail']).forEach(function(index, key) {
  console.log(key, response['orderdetail'][index])
  this.historys.push(response['orderdetail'][index]);
});
```

Look like `this.historys` is not `historys: any = [];`,
How to do this.

Comment: What does `this` refers to in `this.historys.push`? Where have you defined `historys`?

Comment: actually first param to callback of forEach is not index but element and second one is index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is in the foreach function, you've lost your `this` context and it has changed. You can pass the context as an argument to foreach.

```
Object.keys(response['orderdetail']).forEach(function(index, key) {
  console.log(key, response['orderdetail'][index])
  this.historys.push(response['orderdetail'][index]);
}, this);
// ^^^^ this will keep the this context
```